# TreeMap with generic key types

Tags: java, treemap

I am using a TreeMap to add entries that are of type `<Integer,Long>`. However, I may have cases where the entries will be of type `<Long, Long>` and I would like to construct a TreeMap that can handle both cases. So far, I have

```
public class myClass {
    public TreeMap<Integer, String> myClass(String fileToRead) {
        ....
        TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();    
        map.put(Integer, String); //this is a for loop that iterates through input list
    }
    return map
}
```

How do I add a generic key K that can be Integer or Long?

Edit: I would like to include other types, such as BigInteger

Comment: By `Int` you mean `Integer`? because there is no such thing as `Int`.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it.

Comment: Can you also show us how you intend to use this class, with regard to the two types?

Comment: If you put a value using a key of 1 and then a key of 1L, what would you want to happen? Two entries or one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may want something like

```
public class MyClass<T extends Number> {
  public TreeMap<T, String> myClass(String fileToRead) {
  ...
}
```

`BigInteger` too would fill the `Number` bill.

But to avoid the complication with the generics, I would actually suggest to always use `Long` as the key type or even `BigInteger`, except you have strong requirements not to do so. Depending on the JVM you use (64bit) an `Integer` object may not even use less space than a `Long` object.

Answer (score 1):

The super type of both is Number so you can use this

Comment: If you put a value using a key of 1 and then a key of 1L, what happens? And would that be desirable?

Comment: After that you have two Keys - Integer(1) and Long(1) and if it is what you desire depends on the problem to be solved

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the `ReferenceType` with the `instanceof` operator and work accordingly:

```
if (obj instanceof Long) { ... }
if (obj instanceof Integer) { ... }
```

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#15.20.2):

> RelationalExpression `instanceof` ReferenceType
>
> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is true if the value of the `RelationalExpression` is not `null` and the reference could be cast (§15.16) to the `ReferenceType` without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is `false`.